# Rake DEPRECATION WARNING

Tags: rake, warnings, constants, deprecated, initialization

I'm having problems creating a db test. When I use `./script/sync_testenv.sh` I get this error:

```
draco351@draco351-virtual-machine:~/gamersmafia$ sudo ./script/sync_testenv.sh
(in /home/draco351/gamersmafia)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Rake tasks in vendor/plugins/jrails/tasks, vendor/plugins/paperclip/tasks, vendor/plugins/rails_rcov/tasks, and vendor/plugins/restful_authentication/tasks are deprecated. Use lib/tasks instead. (called from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.10/lib/tasks/rails.rb:10)
** Invoke db:test:clone_structure (first_time)
** Execute db:test:clone_structure
** Invoke db:test:create (first_time)
** Execute db:test:create
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant WWW
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load_missing_constant'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:106:in `const_missing'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:118:in `const_missing'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/blackbook-1.0.4/lib/blackbook/importer/page_scraper.rb:7
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/blackbook-1.0.4/lib/blackbook/importer/gmail.rb:1
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/blackbook-1.0.4/lib/blackbook.rb:68
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/blackbook-1.0.4/lib/blackbook.rb:68:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/blackbook-1.0.4/lib/blackbook.rb:68
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:58:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:58:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/home/draco351/gamersmafia/config/environment.rb:38
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.10/lib/initializer.rb:111:in `run'
/home/draco351/gamersmafia/config/environment.rb:9
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.10/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/home/draco351/gamersmafia/lib/tasks/db.rake:24
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/home/draco351/gamersmafia/lib/tasks/db.rake:44
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

This is the project:

https://github.com/Draco351/gamersmafia

And I have the next gems:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

aasm (2.2.0)
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.9, 2.3.10)
actionpack (2.3.10)
activemodel (3.0.9)
activerecord (2.3.10)
activeresource (2.3.10)
activesupport (2.3.10)
ai4r (1.9)
arel (2.0.10)
blackbook (1.0.4)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.15)
capistrano (2.6.0)
ci_reporter (1.6.5)
classifier (1.3.3)
curb (0.7.15)
daemon_controller (0.2.6)
erubis (2.6.6)
fast-stemmer (1.0.0)
fastercsv (1.5.4)
fastthread (1.0.7)
feedbag (0.6)
feedzirra (0.0.20)
file-tail (1.0.6)
geoip (1.1.1)
gruff (0.3.6)
haml (3.1.2)
highline (1.6.2)
hoe (2.10.0)
hpricot (0.8.4)
i18n (0.5.0)
json_pure (1.5.3)
loofah (1.0.0)
mail (2.2.19)
mechanize (2.0.1)
mime-types (1.16)
net-http-digest_auth (1.1.1)
net-http-persistent (1.8)
net-scp (1.0.4)
net-sftp (2.0.5)
net-ssh (2.1.4)
net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
nokogiri (1.5.0)
passenger (3.0.2)
pg (0.11.0)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.1.2)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (2.3.10)
railties (3.0.9)
rake (0.8.7)
rcov (0.9.9)
rdoc (3.8)
rmagick (2.13.1)
rubyforge (2.0.4)
rubygems-update (1.6.2)
rubystats (0.2.3)
sax-machine (0.0.16)
scrubyt (0.4.06)
spruz (0.2.10)
stemmer (1.0.1)
thor (0.14.6)
tidy (1.1.2)
treetop (1.4.9)
tzinfo (0.3.29)
webrobots (0.0.10)
```

I have tried a lot of things but I can't find any solution. There are no problems when I create a new database with these commands:

```
createdb gamersmafia
psql -f db/create.sql gamersmafia
```

But the problems, as I said, arise when I want to execute a db test with `./script/sync_testenv.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

when use Bundler, the documentation suggests:

1. remove any "config.gem"
2. run rake tasks with bundler initialization, like this **bundle exec rake db:test:clone_structure**

Comment: why [this](https://github.com/Draco351/gamersmafia/blob/production/config/boot.rb#L109) conditional expression is needed?